# Передача дополнительного параметра на сервер через $.ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, knockoutjs

Имеется  метод Api контроллера

```
    [System.Web.Http.Route("GenerateReport")]
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs(HttpMethods.Post)]
    public virtual List<TReportItem> GenerateReport(TViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return GetGridItems(viewModel);
    }
```

Через  KnockoutJS на кнопку забиндено :

```
self.generateReport = function () {
            self.beginLoading();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: "@Url.ReporingUrl("GenerateReport", "ImportantApi")",
                data: self.getModel(),
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    self.dataSource.removeAll();
                    self.moveToPage(0);
                    if ($.isArray(data)) {
                        self.dataSource(data);
                        self.calculateAggegates(data);
                    }
                },
                complete: function () {
                    self.endLoading();
                }
            });
        };
```

Хочу расширить метод GenerateReport передав в него дополнительный типа Enum означающий тип отчета.

```
 public virtual List<TReportItem> GenerateReport(TViewModel viewModel, ReportOutputType reptype)
```

Вопрос, как нужно "перешаманить" data чтобы передать на сервер данный параметр

Comment: зависит от настроек роутинга. Например, вы можете попытаться передать его как часть url - `http://example.com/ImportantApi/GenerateReport/myreporttype` или, например, как параметр `http://example.com/ImportantApi/GenerateReport?reptype=myreporttype`

Comment: Да я там помимо Viewmodel, хочу еще элемент enum передать